# about the use of inject in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails

please somebody if you can explain the 3 rd line of this code. This method is to subtract an array of numbers starting from 2nd no. subtracted from 1st and the 3rd no. subtracted from the resultant and so on...

```
def subtract(*numbers)

  sum = numbers.shift

  numbers.inject(sum) { |sum, number| sum - number }  

end
```

Answer (score 0):

http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject

What inject does is takes some initial value (sum) and applies some operation to it for each element of your enumerable. So here, we take 1, and subtract the first element from 1, and the subtract the second element from that result, etc...

So below we have `1 - 2 = -1`, then `-1 - 3 = -4`.

```
>> numbers=[1,2,3]
=> [1, 2, 3]
>> sum = numbers.shift
=> 1
>> numbers
=> [2, 3]
>> numbers.inject(sum) { |sum, number| sum - number }
=> -4
```